# ng bootstrap progressbar type is not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

My project is in Angular and I installed ng bootstrap. I added modules to my app.module.ts the components are working but I can't change the color of progressbar. All types are coming in pink color.

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <ngb-progressbar type="success" height="15px" [value]="25">success</ngb-progressbar>
      <ngb-progressbar class="mt-4" type="info" height="15px" [value]="50">info</ngb-progressbar>
      <ngb-progressbar class="mt-4" type="warning" height="15px" [value]="75">warning</ngb-progressbar>
      <ngb-progressbar class="mt-4" type="danger" height="15px" [value]="100">danger</ngb-progressbar>
      <ngb-progressbar class="mt-4"type="primary" height="15px" [value]="75">primary</ngb-progressbar>
      <ngb-progressbar class="mt-4" type="secondary" height="15px" [value]="50">secondary</ngb-progressbar>
      <ngb-progressbar class="mt-4" type="dark" height="15px" [value]="25">dark</ngb-progressbar>
   </div>
</div>
```

***Output***
[image]

If I wrote this line in my style.scss file I can change the color but I need type attribute. Also I tried injecting NgbProgressbarConfig to my home.component.ts but it didn't work.

```
.progress-bar
{
    background-color: aqua !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not "magic" in ngb-progressbar. This component create a div with class

```
progress-bar text-bg-success   if type=success
//or
progress-bar text-bg-info      if type=info
//or
progress-bar text-bg-warning   if type=warning
//or
...
```

This class are defined in bootstrap.min.css If you override this classes or simply override the progress-bar class with `!important"

```
.progress-bar {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

All your progress bar becomes with the new class

Check where are you override the class. To see, in navigator open the tools, check what .css is override. Generally you have a place where put "css claculated"

Comment: I see. The theme has progress-bar and it's color is pink but how can I use ng bootstrap's themes for progress bars? I want to change progress bar value and color according to my data from typescript.

Comment: @CaptainTaro. To use ng-bootstrap you should import the bootstrap.min.css. -or boostrap.scss- (only the .css or .scss files). Generally you download the .files in a folder of your app ((don't use the "assets" folder) ). Then add in angular.json file (in the array projects --> architect --> build --> styles). Angular join all the .css in this array plus the .css of the components in an unique bundle. If you want to import the .sass

Answer (score 0):

You can change color of text-bg-attribute like this

```
.text-bg-success {
    background-color: pink !important;
  }
  .text-bg-info {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e2ybc2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogressbar-basic.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fprogressbar-basic.ts

Comment: I guess in my code "type="success" is not working at all. First I need to fix this situation then I can use your example. Thanks.